# robotframework how to handle element without resource or how do I custom insert unique text

Tags: robotframework

I have an element which properties does not has resource id or text for me to construct a good element.

on execution, appium does not able to tap anything and passed.

Is the variables in test case defined correctly? i used class=....

or any method I can construct the locator myself?

**the hierachy as below:**

```
<node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.LinearLayout" package="com.test.aa.work.cac" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[0,1411][1440,2792]">
    <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.test.aa.work.cac:id/fab_group" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test.aa.work.cac" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[124,1411][1440,2792]">
        <node index="0" text="" resource-id="com.test.aa.work.cac:id/fab_button" class="android.view.ViewGroup" package="com.test.aa.work.cac" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[124,1411][1398,2757]">
            <node NAF="true" index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageButton" package="com.test.aa.work.cac" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="true" enabled="true" focusable="true" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="true" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1166,2511][1398,2757]"/>
            <node index="1" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.FrameLayout" package="com.test.aa.work.cac" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1240,2592][1324,2676]">
                <node index="0" text="" resource-id="" class="android.widget.ImageView" package="com.test.aa.work.cac" content-desc="" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" scrollable="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" selected="false" bounds="[1240,2592][1324,2676]"/>
            </node>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

**test case:**

```
*** Variables ***
${compose-new-mail}    class=android.widget.ImageButton
${compose-new-mail2}    class=android.widget.ImageView
${compose-new-mail3}    class=android.widget.FrameLayout

*** Test Cases ***
Open Application
   Open Application  ....xxx
   appiumlibrary.tap    ${compose-new-mail3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that there are multiple elements that has android.widget.FrameLayout class.
Also the correct locator would be

```
//*[@class='android.widget.FrameLayout']
```

I recommend you these for further explore:

https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Tap
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html